# Why does a new command create a space?

Tags: spacing, macros, sectioning

In the below code, I create my own little macro which makes a subsubsection heading. I then call the macro and type out verbatim what the macro says, and I get a different spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\eepoint}[1]{\vspace{3mm}\par\refstepcounter{subsubsection}\noindent{\bf \thesubsubsection.}   {\em #1.}
}
\begin{document}
\eepoint{A buncha stuff} And some more stuff
\vspace{3mm}\par\refstepcounter{subsubsection}\noindent{\bf \thesubsubsection.}   {\em A buncha stuff.} And some more stuff
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is that space that is added there?

I actually like it: I think it looks nice. So if I type out everything the macro says manually, how do I produce the exact same spacing?

Also, sometimes when I do it manually, I get a little indent. (It hasn't shown up in this MWE for some reason: often the 0.0.2. line is indented just a little). Any ideas about fixing this?

Comment: The end of line after `{\em #1}`

Comment: If you used a real heading or list item code latex would take some care not to have this failing (mostly by not using `\noindent`)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines

Comment: The end of the definition of `\eepoint` contains the phrase  `{\em #1.} `. TeX' reading apparatus attaches a space at the end of each line of input. Thus there is a space at the closing brace that gets tokenized as space token.  This space token will be "spit out" whenever `\eepoint` gets expanded. (Can be avoided by `%` at ends of lines.) In the document-body, the call `\eepoint{A buncha stuff} And some more stuff` also contains a space behind the closing brace which gets tokenized too. Therefore summa sumarum you get **two** consecutive space tokens, each of them delivering horizontal space.

Comment: If you like more horizontal space, consider using the `\quad`-command. Afaik it delivers horizontal space in the width of the capital letter M. Or `\qquad` delivers horizontal space in the width twice of the capital letter M.  If you do so, consider using `\ignorespaces` at the end of the definition of your macro for ensuring spaces after the closing brace of the argument of `\eepoint` don't deliver additional horizontal space.

Answer (score 12):

You can adjust the spacing to whatever values you need but

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\eepoint[1]{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {3.25ex\@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                     {-1em}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\mdseries\itshape#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\eepoint{A buncha stuff} And some more stuff
\vspace{3mm}\par\refstepcounter{subsubsection}\noindent{\bf \thesubsubsection.}   {\em A buncha stuff.} And some more stuff
\end{document}
```

done this way LaTeX will take care of white space in the document

```
\eepoint{A buncha stuff} And some more stuff
```

is the same as

```
\eepoint{A buncha stuff}And some more stuff
```

or

```
\eepoint{A buncha stuff}
And some more stuff
```

Also page breaking near the heading etc.